# How can I change the Lock Screen (not Wallpapewaar) background?

Tags: lock-screen

Currently I want to change the lock screen picture. I cannotyucg ewww w set it to another picture that I want. The current pictures are the ones I set up when I first installed Ubuntu.

I can change wallpaper as usual, using right-click anhhgjhsigbd **Set as Wallpaper**. But I don't want to set it as wallpaper but as Lock Screen. How do I change the picture that I've set?

Comment: On which version of Ubuntu are you ? Which is your desktop environment ? Gnome, Unity, other ?

Comment: You didn't give your version of Ubuntu as already asked, so I'll assume it's the latest & default.  Check out the documentation page https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-background.html.en  (it will change workspace background & lock screen background)

Comment: I've check the link and already follow the steps. But as I said, it didn't change to Lock Screen but it change the Wallpaper instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Desktop**

[please note: this is copied straight from Ubuntu documentation, it's worth a look :)](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-background.html.en)

You can change the image used for your backgrounds or set it to be a solid color.

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Background.
2. Click on Background to open the panel.
3. Select the Background or **Lock Screen**.
4. There are three choices displayed on top:

> Select Wallpapers to use one of the many professional background
>   images that ship with GNOME. Some wallpapers change throughout the
>   day. These wallpapers have a small clock icon in the bottom-right
>   corner.
>
> Select Pictures to use one of your own photos from your Pictures
>   folder. Most photo management applications store photos there. If you
>   would like to use an image that is not in your Pictures folder, either
>   use Files by right-clicking on the image file and selecting Set as
>   Wallpaper, or Image Viewer by opening the image file, clicking the
>   menu button in the titlebar and selecting Set as Wallpaper.

1. Select Colors to just use a flat color.
2. The settings are applied immediately.

When done, switch to an empty workspace to view your entire desktop.

Comment: You could have a heading **Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Desktop**...

Comment: I don't know why I cannot see all pics in the Pictures folder, only parts of them.